# getting some errors and a crash after changing API level on Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin, crash, android-api-levels

recently i have bought a source code and applying some changes and tested the app, everything worked perfect! except that i don't actually get notifications on the app the whole time but i will find a solution for that later... after trying to upload my app on Google Play it said that i have to have API level 29 as a minimum while i'm only having 27, i changed it by going to Project Structure and following the steps and when i tested the app on my phone, it opens normally but once i click on "menu" button it get crashed! i have searched a lot about the errors i found on the logcat but nothing worked for me. Hope you help me.

Errors on Logcat :

```
2020-07-22 14:43:07.004 9831-9831/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
2020-07-22 14:43:07.006 9831-9831/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 1
2020-07-22 14:43:11.641 9831-9831/com.reflection.water.time E/chromium: [ERROR:filesystem_posix.cc(62)] mkdir /data/user/0/com.reflection.water.time/cache/WebView/Crashpad: No such file or directory (2)
2020-07-22 14:43:23.714 9831-9831/com.reflection.water.time E/chromium: [ERROR:aw_browser_terminator.cc(125)] Renderer process (9974) crash detected (code -1).
2020-07-22 14:43:28.232 9831-9831/com.reflection.water.time E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() returned.
2020-07-22 14:43:33.482 9831-9831/com.reflection.water.time E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() returned.
2020-07-22 14:43:44.827 9831-9831/com.reflection.water.time E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.reflection.water.time, PID: 9831
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid Region.Op - only INTERSECT and DIFFERENCE are allowed
        at android.graphics.Canvas.checkValidClipOp(Canvas.java:779)
        at android.graphics.Canvas.clipPath(Canvas.java:1007)
        at co.ceryle.radiorealbutton.RoundedCornerLayout.dispatchDraw(RoundedCornerLayout.java:80)
        at android.view.View.buildDrawingCacheImpl(View.java:21131)
        at android.view.View.buildDrawingCache(View.java:20997)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21586)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4558)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4333)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.dispatchDraw(ConstraintLayout.java:2023)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21871)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20741)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21594)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4558)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4333)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21871)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20741)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21594)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4558)
        at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.drawChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1246)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4333)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20727)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21594)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4558)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4333)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20727)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21594)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4558)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4333)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20727)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21594)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4558)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4333)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20727)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21594)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4558)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4333)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20727)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21594)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4558)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4333)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20727)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21594)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4558)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4333)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21871)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.draw(DecorView.java:1129)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20741)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:725)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:731)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:840)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:3968)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:3742)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:3053)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1916)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8554)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:949)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:761)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:696)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:935)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7078)
2020-07-22 14:43:44.827 9831-9831/com.reflection.water.time E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
```

AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          package="com.reflection.water.time">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

    <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
        <activity android:name="com.reflection.water.time.WalkThroughActivity"
                  android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        <activity
                android:name="com.reflection.water.time.StatsActivity"
                android:theme="@style/MainTheme"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.reflection.water.time.InitUserInfoActivity"
                  android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        <activity
                android:name="com.reflection.water.time.MainActivity"
                android:theme="@style/MainTheme"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name="com.reflection.water.time.recievers.NotifierReceiver"/>
        <receiver android:name="com.reflection.water.time.recievers.BootReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AD_MANAGER_APP"
                android:value="true"/>

        <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
                android:value="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713"/>

        <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity :

```
package com.reflection.water.time

import android.content.Intent
import android.content.SharedPreferences
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Handler
import android.text.TextUtils
import android.util.TypedValue
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.reflection.water.time.fragments.BottomSheetFragment
import com.reflection.water.time.helpers.AlarmHelper
import com.reflection.water.time.helpers.SqliteHelper
import com.reflection.water.time.utils.AdsUtility
import com.reflection.water.time.utils.AppUtils
import com.daimajia.androidanimations.library.Techniques
import com.daimajia.androidanimations.library.YoYo
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar
import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var totalIntake: Int = 0
    private var inTook: Int = 0
    private lateinit var sharedPref: SharedPreferences
    private lateinit var sqliteHelper: SqliteHelper
    private lateinit var dateNow: String
    private var notificStatus: Boolean = false
    private var selectedOption: Int? = null
    private var snackbar: Snackbar? = null
    private var doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false
    private lateinit var banner : LinearLayout


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        MobileAds.initialize(this, AdsUtility.admobAppId)

        sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(AppUtils.USERS_SHARED_PREF, AppUtils.PRIVATE_MODE)
        sqliteHelper =
            SqliteHelper(this)

        AdsUtility.InterstitialAdmob(this)

        totalIntake = sharedPref.getInt(AppUtils.TOTAL_INTAKE, 0)

        if (sharedPref.getBoolean(AppUtils.FIRST_RUN_KEY, true)) {
            startActivity(Intent(this, WalkThroughActivity::class.java))
            finish()
        } else if (totalIntake <= 0) {
            startActivity(Intent(this, InitUserInfoActivity::class.java))
            finish()
        }


        dateNow = AppUtils.getCurrentDate()!!

        banner = findViewById(R.id.banner)
        AdsUtility.admobBannerCall(this, banner)

    }

    fun updateValues() {
        totalIntake = sharedPref.getInt(AppUtils.TOTAL_INTAKE, 0)

        inTook = sqliteHelper.getIntook(dateNow)

        setWaterLevel(inTook, totalIntake)
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()

        val outValue = TypedValue()
        applicationContext.theme.resolveAttribute(
            android.R.attr.selectableItemBackground,
            outValue,
            true
        )

        notificStatus = sharedPref.getBoolean(AppUtils.NOTIFICATION_STATUS_KEY, true)
        val alarm = AlarmHelper()
        if (!alarm.checkAlarm(this) && notificStatus) {
            btnNotific.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_bell))
            alarm.setAlarm(
                this,
                sharedPref.getInt(AppUtils.NOTIFICATION_FREQUENCY_KEY, 30).toLong()
            )
        }

        if (notificStatus) {
            btnNotific.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_bell))
        } else {
            btnNotific.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_bell_disabled))
        }

        sqliteHelper.addAll(dateNow, 0, totalIntake)

        updateValues()

        btnMenu.setOnClickListener {
            val bottomSheetFragment =
                BottomSheetFragment(
                    this
                )
            bottomSheetFragment.show(supportFragmentManager, bottomSheetFragment.tag)
            AdsUtility.showIntestitialAds()
        }

        fabAdd.setOnClickListener {
            if (selectedOption != null) {
                if ((inTook * 100 / totalIntake) <= 140) {
                    if (sqliteHelper.addIntook(dateNow, selectedOption!!) > 0) {
                        inTook += selectedOption!!
                        setWaterLevel(inTook, totalIntake)

                        Snackbar.make(it, "Your water intake was saved...!!", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show()

                    }
                } else {
                    Snackbar.make(it, "You already achieved the goal", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
                selectedOption = null
                tvCustom.text = "Custom"
                op50ml.background = getDrawable(outValue.resourceId)
                op100ml.background = getDrawable(outValue.resourceId)
                op150ml.background = getDrawable(outValue.resourceId)
                op200ml.background = getDrawable(outValue.resourceId)
                op250ml.background = getDrawable(outValue.resourceId)
                opCustom.background = getDrawable(outValue.resourceId)
            } else {
                YoYo.with(Techniques.Shake)
                    .duration(700)
                    .playOn(cardView)
                Snackbar.make(it, "Please select an option", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }

        btnNotific.setOnClickListener {
            notificStatus = !notificStatus
            sharedPref.edit().putBoolean(AppUtils.NOTIFICATION_STATUS_KEY, notificStatus).apply()
            if (notificStatus) {
                btnNotific.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_bell))
                Snackbar.make(it, "Notification Enabled..", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                alarm.setAlarm(
                    this,
                    sharedPref.getInt(AppUtils.NOTIFICATION_FREQUENCY_KEY, 30).toLong()
                )
            } else {
                btnNotific.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_bell_disabled))
                Snackbar.make(it, "Notification Disabled..", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                alarm.cancelAlarm(this)
            }
        }

        btnStats.setOnClickListener {
            startActivity(Intent(this, StatsActivity::class.java))
            AdsUtility.showIntestitialAds()
        }


        op50ml.setOnClickListener {
            if (snackbar != null) {
                snackbar?.dismiss()
            }
            selectedOption = 50
            op50ml.background = getDrawable(R.drawable.option_select_bg)
            op100ml.background = getDrawable(outValue.resourceId)
            op150ml.background = getDrawable(outValue.resourceId)
            op200ml.background = getDrawable(outValue.resourceId)
            op250ml.background = getDrawable(outValue.resourceId)
            opCustom.background = getDrawable(outValue.resourceId)

        }

        op100ml.setOnClickListener {
            if (snackbar != null) {
                snackbar?.dismiss()
            }
            selectedOption = 100
            op50ml.background = getDrawable(outValue.resourceId)
            op100ml.background = getDrawable(R.drawable.option_select_bg)
            op150ml.background = getDrawable(outValue.resourceId)
            op200ml.background = getDrawable(outValue.resourceId)
            op250ml.background = getDrawable(outValue.resourceId)
            opCustom.background = getDrawable(outValue.resourceId)

        }

        op150ml.setOnClickListener {
            if (snackbar != null) {
                snackbar?.dismiss()
            }
            selectedOption = 150
            op50ml.background = getDrawable(outValue.resourceId)
            op100ml.background = getDrawable(outValue.resourceId)
            op150ml.background = getDrawable(R.drawable.option_select_bg)
            op200ml.background = getDrawable(outValue.resourceId)
            op250ml.background = getDrawable(outValue.resourceId)
            opCustom.background = getDrawable(outValue.resourceId)

        }

        op200ml.setOnClickListener {
            if (snackbar != null) {
                snackbar?.dismiss()
            }
            selectedOption = 200
            op50ml.background = getDrawable(outValue.resourceId)
            op100ml.background = getDrawable(outValue.resourceId)
            op150ml.background = getDrawable(outValue.resourceId)
            op200ml.background = getDrawable(R.drawable.option_select_bg)
            op250ml.background = getDrawable(outValue.resourceId)
            opCustom.background = getDrawable(outValue.resourceId)

        }

        op250ml.setOnClickListener {
            if (snackbar != null) {
                snackbar?.dismiss()
            }
            selectedOption = 250
            op50ml.background = getDrawable(outValue.resourceId)
            op100ml.background = getDrawable(outValue.resourceId)
            op150ml.background = getDrawable(outValue.resourceId)
            op200ml.background = getDrawable(outValue.resourceId)
            op250ml.background = getDrawable(R.drawable.option_select_bg)
            opCustom.background = getDrawable(outValue.resourceId)

        }

        opCustom.setOnClickListener {
            if (snackbar != null) {
                snackbar?.dismiss()
            }

            val li = LayoutInflater.from(this)
            val promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.custom_input_dialog, null)

            val alertDialogBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView)

            val userInput = promptsView
                .findViewById(R.id.etCustomInput) as TextInputLayout

            alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK") { dialog, id ->
                val inputText = userInput.editText!!.text.toString()
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(inputText)) {
                    tvCustom.text = "${inputText} ml"
                    selectedOption = inputText.toInt()
                }
            }.setNegativeButton("Cancel") { dialog, id ->
                dialog.cancel()
            }

            val alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create()
            alertDialog.show()

            op50ml.background = getDrawable(outValue.resourceId)
            op100ml.background = getDrawable(outValue.resourceId)
            op150ml.background = getDrawable(outValue.resourceId)
            op200ml.background = getDrawable(outValue.resourceId)
            op250ml.background = getDrawable(outValue.resourceId)
            opCustom.background = getDrawable(R.drawable.option_select_bg)

        }

    }


    private fun setWaterLevel(inTook: Int, totalIntake: Int) {

        YoYo.with(Techniques.SlideInDown)
            .duration(500)
            .playOn(tvIntook)
        tvIntook.text = "$inTook"
        tvTotalIntake.text = "/$totalIntake ml"
        val progress = ((inTook / totalIntake.toFloat()) * 100).toInt()
        YoYo.with(Techniques.Pulse)
            .duration(500)
            .playOn(intakeProgress)
        intakeProgress.currentProgress = progress
        if ((inTook * 100 / totalIntake) > 140) {
            Snackbar.make(main_activity_parent, "You achieved the goal", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show()
        }
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
            super.onBackPressed()
            return
        }

        this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true
        Snackbar.make(
            this.window.decorView.findViewById(android.R.id.content),
            "Please click BACK again to exit",
            Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT
        ).show()

        Handler().postDelayed({ doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false }, 1000)
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/main_activity_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_app_bg"
        tools:context="com.reflection.water.time.MainActivity">

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btnMenu"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_settings"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

build.gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.reflection.water.time"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 5
        versionName "1.3"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```